If I click a link directly from a textfield, does onblur consistently fire before the link?
I have a text input and a link used as a button set up on my website like so:
<input type="text" onblur="blurfunction()">
<a href="javascript:buttonfunction()">Button</a>

It's important for my functionality to have blurfunction() always fire before buttonfunction(), even if the link is clicked directly without exiting the text field. From my limited testing in latest Chrome and Firefox clicking on the link directly from the text field consistently deselects the text field and fires blurfunction() before handling the link click and firing buttonfunction().
The specification for the blur event type specifies:

The focus MUST be taken from the element before the dispatch of this event type.

The specification for the focus event type specifies:

The focus MUST be given to the element before the dispatch of this event type.

While the specification for each individual event is pretty clear on the order things are handled for each element separately, I'm not sure if there's anything in here that specifically states that the blur event gets dispatched before the focus is given to the next element.
Can I expect this behaviour to be consistent across all browsers/devices? Is the order these calls happen defined in the HTML/JavaScript spec or could implementations differ between browsers?

The blur event will always fire before the click event as long as the input has the focus before the link is clicked. But on another note, you should not be using a hyperlink  unless it's for navigation. If not, just use a button.

@ScottMarcus is there anything in the spec that would confirm this order of events? An answer along those lines would apply to using a button as well I think (also the decision to use a hyperlink was made over a decade ago and if I was able to make that change I would)

did you tried to use the same handler for both events and manage the logic according to target, elements, events in the function? In this way you don't need to depends on the events or elements behavior, just control it in the handler.

I'd also like to point out that my question is not "How can I guarantee these functions are called in order," which is fairly trivial but "Is it guaranteed these events fire in order," which is completely different

I believe the events should be in the order you expect.
When you click on the link, the first event that occurs is mousedown. The specification says that the focusing steps are run at the target of the mousedown. If you then read the specification of focus update steps, this step includes triggering the change and blur events on the input element.
The link isn't followed until you finish clicking on the link, which is after the mouseup.

Exactly the answer I was expecting, thanks! Going into details would be helpful here though if you're willing to edit those into your answer

I fixed that link, and added a link to the focus update steps.

It's hard to say if it will be consistent between ALL browsers, especially with the weirdness that can happen with the touch interface on mobile devices.
There are dozens of different browsers and hundreds/thousands of versions between them. It's hard to say definitively whether the same Bubbling/DOM propagation would work the same. If you go by the JavaScript spec with DOM event bubbling and utilize the correct event listeners it should work. However, the only way I'm aware of to be 100% sure would be to call the blurFunction in your code for the buttonFunction.
function buttonFunction (){
    blurFunction()
}

Also, would recommend using a semantic <button onclick=""></button> for your code instead of styling a <a href="" />

I'm asking specifically for a definitive answer on whether the behaviour will or will not be consistent - I can't call the blur function within the button function due to a different requirement

Edited my question to be clearer on what I'd be looking for in a definitive answer
